# Python logical values expressions and interpretations

Tags: python

I really have no idea where I should start on this problem. My task is to write a function interpret that takes two arguments: a logical expression and an interpretation (a table where each proposition symbol is assigned the value true or false). The interpretation should be made in the form of a dictionary.

A logical expression can be one of the following (and nothing else):

- one of the logical constants `"true"` or `"false"` (which should be these strings, not true and false)
- a proposition symbol within quotation marks, such as `"p"`, `"q"`, `"cat_gone"`
- an expression of the form `["NOT", <logical expression>]`
- an expression of the form `[logical expression 1, "OR", logical expression 2]`
- an expression of the form `[logical expression 1, "AND", logical expression 2]`

An example of an invalid expression in this logic is `["cat_asleep", "OR", "door_open", "OR", "cat_gone"]`.

The task is to write a function interpret that takes two arguments, a valid expression and an interpretation, and gives the truth about whether the whole expression is true in this particular interpretation. The logical constants and expressions should be managed as strings, so you need to implement their own functions for the Boolean operations.

Example input and output

```
interpret(["door_open", "AND", "cat_gone"], 
           {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"} )
'false'   

interpret(["cat_asleep", "OR", ["NOT", "cat_gone"]],
               {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"})
'true'
```

Can someone please explain to me what I'm supposed to do here and how to approach this problem? I know it's explained fairly well but I just don't understand it. Are there some videos or guides that goes through a problem like this one?

Comment: What's the first part that's unclear?

Comment: @melpomene The input for the expression is a list that can contain lists, do I have to use double recursion here? What do they mean by "the logical constants and expressions should be managed as strings, so you need to implement their own functions for the Boolean operations."? What happens in the first example? The` ["door_open", "AND", "cat_gone"]` is the expression and `{"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"}` is the interpretation but how does it work?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "double recursion". They mean the values in the dictionary are strings (`"true"` or `"false"`), and you shouldn't use the built-in boolean type to implement `interpret`. `door_open` and `cat_gone` are variables that are looked up in the dictionary. Their values are `"false"` and `"true"`, respectively. Logically, `false and true` is `false`, so the result is the string `"false"`.